# Throw away any changes to a file

Tags: linux, files

Is there any way to listen for changes on a file and
a) Immediately restore the file
or
b) Make the editing program (e.g. `sed -i`, `truncate`) believe that it has written to the file while throwing away any edits

Basically I want programs to be able to read a file, and even think that they are modifying it, while leaving the file untouched (or replaced with the original as soon as possible)

Edit: someone asked for my used case
I am working with two programs. The first (`master`) is set up to manage a second program (`slave`). Part of `master`'s job is to create a configuration file for `slave`. I need to change a property of the config file that `master` seems to have hardcoded. Unfortunately, `master` is only available as a compiled binary, so I can't change the file it writes to or what it writes. `slave` can only accept configuration from the file that `master` generates, and while it never changes, if edit access is revoked from the file (e.g. `chmod 444`) then `master` crashes. This leads to the need for what is essentially a race attack between the time that `master` changes the file and `slave` is started.

Comment: Would just feeding those programs a copy of the original file work? It would be interesting to know your use case.

Comment: By default, `sed` sends the changes to stdout and doesn't modify the file unless the `-i` option is used.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I have updated the question with an vague-ized version of my use case. Let me know if you need more details

Comment: Do you have the code for `slave`? And, do you know if `master`'s binary is static? (thinking about doing some shared library interception. A `file master_file_name` should give you that information. By the way, `inotify-wait` should help, if you listen for the `close` event, but you would still have the race condition, it's best to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Some Idea:

- Have a look at union file-systems. There is a (at least 2) fuse one.
- Write a wrapper script for `slave`, have it restore the file, and then exec `slave`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a choice run master and slave as different users. Then chmod 644 will allow master to write (so it won't crash), and slave - to read.